# Checking for Adjacent elements in 2d Arrays and replacing them

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So, I am building a method to check a 2d array for a target value and replace each adjacent element with that target value. I have literally tried to brainstorm the solution to this for about an hour and I just want to know if anyone can help me with this, this is the code I have so far

```
 public int[][] replaceValue(int n, int[][]y){
int [][]temp0 = new int[y.length][y[0].length];
int[]top, down ,left, right = new int[y[0].length];
for(int row = 0; row < y.length; row++){
  for(int col = 0; col < y[row].length; col++){
    temp0[row][col] = y[row][col];// new array so I wouldn't mess with the array passed in
  }
}
for(int row = 0; row < temp0.length; row++){
  for(int col = 0; col < temp0[row].length; col++){
    top[row] = temp0[row-1][col];
    down[row] = temp0[row+1][col];
    right[row] = temp0[row][col+1];
    left[row] = temp0[row] [col-1];
  }
}
```

I got error messages such as I didn't initialize my top and left and right and down variables but I simply don't understand how the logic works for checking the adjacent elements and making sure the whole array is not replaced with the target value. Thanks

Comment: Your method is not completely ended. plz modify it to return desired value.

Comment: I had it completed but my logic was stupid and  I just posted the first part where it told me I needed to initialize, sorry I am just trying to understand it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is a little confusing so I will try to interpret it.

What you are given is a 2-dimensional array with some integer values. Your function should scan the 2-d array, and if you find some target value, 
 return a 2-d array with the adjacent indices as the target value as well.

For example, if we have a 3x3 array and the target is 2...

```
1 1 1       1 2 1
1 2 1 ====> 2 2 2
1 1 1       1 2 1
```

**Your problem** is that you can't think of a way to change the value without changing the entire array to 2.

**Solution One:** You scan for the target value in the *given* array, but you update the values in the *temporary* array.

**Solution Two:** You scan the temporary array, and store whether or not it should be changed using a 2-d boolean array.

Solution One is much better in terms of efficiency (both memory and time), so I'll just give you *my solution #2*, and leave you to do Solution One on your own.

Also, please use more descriptive variable names when it matters :P (why is the input called temp??)

```
public static int[][] replaceValue(int target, int[][] currArray){
        int[][] temp = new int[currArray.length][];

        //get a boolean array of same size
        //NOTE: it is initialized as false
        boolean[][] needsChange = new boolean[currArray.length][currArray[0].length];

        //copy the current array into temp
        for(int i = 0; i < currArray.length; i++){
            temp[i] = currArray[i].clone();
        }

        //Go through each value in the 2d array
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < temp[0].length; j++){
                //if it is the target value, mark it to be changed
                if(temp[i][j] == target){
                    needsChange[i][j] = true;
                }
            }
        }

        //Go through each value in the 2d array
        for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < temp[0].length; j++){
                if(needsChange[i][j]){ //NOTE: same as "needsChange[i][j] = true;"
                    //Now, we will check to make sure we don't go out of bounds
                    //Top
                    if(i > 0){
                        temp[i-1][j] = target;
                    }

                    //Bottom
                    if(i + 1 < temp.length){
                        temp[i+1][j] = target;
                    }

                    //Left
                    if(j > 0){
                        temp[i][j-1] = target;
                    }

                    //Right
                    if(j + 1 < temp[0].length){
                        temp[i][j+1] = target;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //return the new array we made
        return temp;
    }
```

Comment: Ohh, I was thinking of it more complicated than this, I thought we needed to store the reference of each so we don't have the error of everything being the same but will try this thanks, really explanatory

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized your local variables before first use. So you need to change your 3rd line to some thing like the below code:

```
int[] top = new int[temp[0].length], down = new int[temp[0].length], 
      left = new int[temp[0].length], right = new int[temp[0].length];
```

After that your code is compiled and you can check your logic.

Comment: The real problem here is I want to know how it really works but thanks, maybe my question wasn't all that clear